# Erro na referencia no C#

Tags: c#

estou com esse erro alguém sabe o que é ?

> Warning    1   The primary reference "C:\Users\Denilson\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SistemaEmpilhadeiras\Empilhadeiras.DTO\bin\Debug\Empilhadeiras.DTO.dll" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".  Empilhadeiras.DAO
>
> Warning    2   The referenced project 'Empilhadeiras.DTO' is targeting a higher framework version (4.5) than this project’s current target framework version (4.0). This may lead to build failures if types from assemblies outside this project’s target framework are used by any project in the dependency chain.  Empilhadeiras.DAO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Click direito no projecto "Empilhadeiras.DTO"
2. Properties
3. Escolhe a tab "Application"
4. Em "Target framework", escolha ".NET Framework 4.0"

Alternativamente, podes executar os mesmos passos para alterar a framework do projecto "Empilhadeiras.DAO" para 4.5

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda deixa eu fazer uma pergunta besta trabalho com a V4.0 ou mudo todos para a V4.5 qual a diferença.

Agradeço muito pela ajuda

Comment: Tem aqui uma lista completa das diferencas: [What's new in the .NET Framework 4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#core). Na minha opiniao, a diferenca mais importante foi a introducao do idioma `async`/`await` com o C# 5.0/.NET 4.5.

Comment: De um modo geral: se for um projecto academico, usa a versao mais actual. Se for um projecto que vai ser consumido por outros projectos (ex: uma biblioteca), usa a versao mais baixa possivel de modo a suportar o maior numero de clientes. Se for um projecto que nao vai ser consumido directamente por outros (ex: aplicacao web, aplicacao desktop), entao usa a versao mais actual.

Comment: Muito Obrigado ajudou bastante, Um Grande Abraço

Answer (score 2):

Você provavelmente está referenciando uma DLL que utiliza o Framework .Net 4.5 enquanto no seu projeto usa uma versão do .Net menor a 4.0.

> This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0

Comment: estou fazendo um projeto e só coloquei mais uma classe Empilhadeiras.DTO e deu esse erro, tem alguma solução ?

Comment: O seu projeto tem alguma restrição em relação a poder ou não usar uma versão superior do .Net?